# Why Elastic Beanstalk run old Vuejs modules on new Laravel app version deployment?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js

I am trying to deploy a new version of my Laravel+VueJS app on Elastic Beanstalk.
Everything goes fine, the health status is okay, but when I open the website I see the frontend of the previous version. I can't figure out why I am getting the old frontend and the new version of the Laravel backend at the same time.

I tried to clear all the Laravel cache and to deploy the project again but it doesn't work.

On my home page, the Vue frontend is calling for a route of the previous frontend version. I get 404 error because I deleted "/userIsAdmin" route in the last version web.php route file.

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY1u8.png)

How can I reload the new js modules on the instance?
Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you very much!

Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that in my .env file I had a wrong APP_URL. The server was loading the app.js file from another endpoint in which it was running the previous version of my app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't compiled a production build. Try out:

```
npm run build
```

on your app before you deploy to beanstalk.